# Web.py : After Post, The session variables are initialized

Tags: session, post, web.py

I've already turned off debug mode by setting `web.config.debug = False`

```
class login:
    def GET(self):
        return render.login()

    def POST(self):
        data = json.loads(web.data())
        password = data["password"]
        account = data["account"]

        verify = db.query("SELECT * FROM auth_test "
                          " WHERE account = '%s' "
                          "       and pass = '%s'"%(account, password))
        print(len(verify))
        print(session.flag)

        if len(verify)!=0 :
            session.flag=True
        print(session.flag)

        return len(verify)

        raise web.seeother('/login')
```

**but when I print(session.flag) in other class after successful post, it always shows 0.**

```
app = web.application(urls, globals())

if web.config.get('_session') is None:
    session = web.session.Session(app, web.session.DiskStore('sessions'), {'flag': False})
    web.config._session = session
else:
    session = web.config._session
```

Can anyone tell me why it is?

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to do: "web.session.Session" creates and initializes a user session. It is not the "current" session: web.ctx.session is. The third argument to web.session.Session() is the session initializer: that is, the set of values a new (user) session will get. It's copied into the class and you cannot change it by doing session.flag = True.

Comment: What I want to do is using Session to judge whether the login is successful, when successful login the login flag should be set to True.

Comment: Your code looks ok. I can replicate the error by making the `sessions` subdirectory not writable (or otherwise make it so web.py cannot actually store the session info) -- so a new session is created each time. Check to see what the session ID value is (session.session_id). It should match the value of the cookie, and should not change.